# Unicode string display in XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unicode, xna

In the game I'm making, I'd like to be able to display and have the user input Unicode characters. However, I'm having problems with using SpriteFonts to handle this task. Including all of the Unicode characters uses up WAY too many resources (it even causes VS2010 to crash!), so that's out of the question. But I'm not sure what other options I may have.

I know there are ways to dynamically load Unicode codepoints in an "as-needed" basis, but these methods seem to be geared towards string tables and other static text. All of my text is provided by the user, so a static approach wouldn't work here. Any ideas/help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XNA Forums are a good place to ask XNA questions. Here is a question similar to yours:
http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/3302/16475.aspx#16475